# Set selected value for Select input

Tags: angularjs

I have two objects - `Order` and `Customer`. Now I want to edit `Order`. `Order` have two fileds from `Customer` object.  I want to display list of `Customers` in select option:

```
select(ng-model="customer"
       ng-options="customer.description for customer in vm.customers"
       ng-change="vm.setCustomer(customer)")
```

Here is `setCustomer()` method in the controller:

```
setCustomer = function(customer) {
   this.currentOrder.customerId = customer.autoincrementedId;
   this.currentOrder.customerDescription = customer.description;
}
```

That is work.  I can select `Customer` from the list and it fill two filed in my `currentOrder` object.

But when I load page my select control is empty even if the I have filled `customerId` and `customerDescription` in my `Order`.  I understand that the reason is that `customer` is empty, but I don't know what is the best way to fix it.

How can I fill the `select` when I am opening page ?

Comment: be careful using `this` inside functions, should store a reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `value as text for obj in arr` syntax of `ngOptions` - then set the `ngModel` to the `value`:

```
select(ng-model="customer"
   ng-options="customer.autoincrementedId as customer.description for customer in vm.customers"
   ng-change="vm.setCustomer(customer)")
```

And set `this.customer` to the `autoincrementedId` of the customer you want default selected.

Comment: In this case I will pass only `id` to my function `vm.setCustomer(customer)` and can not set the second field in it.  I can find the `Customer` in my collection by `id`, but may be there is a better way ?

Comment: @demas -- I updated the answer to use `autoincrementedId` (didn't see it before) - on load - assign `this.customer` the `autoincrementedId` you want selected.